# WinForms: No Pending Calls to SuspendLayout()

Tags: c#, winforms

In the Windows Forms documentation for Control.SuspendLayout(), there is the following statement:

> There must be no pending calls to SuspendLayout for ResumeLayout to be
> successfully called.

There's a few loaded phrases in this statement (such as "pending calls").

- What scenario(s) does this statement correspond to?
- What cases do I need to guard against?

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=net-5.0

Comment: You can view the actual implementation of both `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout`: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/a.html#ef45260c5d9215da

Comment: My guess is that the calls are paired and stacked.

Comment: See the brief but *intense* notes in [PerformLayout()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,9903), related to *the sequence* and what the `cachedLayoutEventArgs` object is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they are saying is, you must call `ResumeLayout` one-for-one with `SuspendLayout`.

So, to guard against this state, you could do this:

```
MyControl.SuspendLayout();
try
{
    // do some work
}
finally
{
    MyControl.ResumeLayout();
}
```

That way if the "do some work" block throws an exception, you can be assured that `ResumeLayout` is always called, otherwise the suspend/resume will become unbalanced and your UI will not update properly.

In other words, if you do this:

```
MyControl.SuspendLayout();
MyControl.SuspendLayout();
MyControl.ResumeLayout();
```

then `ResumeLayout` will not have the desired affect.

But, this will:

```
MyControl.SuspendLayout();
MyControl.SuspendLayout();
MyControl.ResumeLayout();
MyControl.ResumeLayout();
```